# Asynchronous waiting for data changed

Tags: c#

I've got a synchronisation question where I have a thread that generates data and puts the data in a list.
I've got other threads that require to either sample "current latest value" or "wait for new data, and then get latest value".

My class that generates data roughly looks like this:

```cs
    public class GeneratingThread
    {
        public delegate void Callback();

        public event EventHandler DataChanged;

        private List<int> dataPayload = new List<int>();

        /* other functions */

        public int GetLastData()
        {
            /* synchronization */
            return dataPayload.Last();
        }

        private void AsyncDataSampler(int data) /* Generates data in intervals of ~1ms */
        {
            /* synchronization */
            dataPayload.Add(data);

            if (DataChanged != null)
                DataChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

And the class that consumes data looks like this:

```
    public class ConsumingThread
    {
        int WaitForMeasurement(AsyncThread otherThread)
        {
            AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            EventHandler waitForEvent = (Object sender, EventArgs args) => autoResetEvent.Set();

            otherThread.DataChanged += waitForEvent;

            autoResetEvent.WaitOne();

            otherThread.DataChanged -= waitForEvent;

            /* do something with the data */
            return otherThread.GetLastData();
        }
    }
```

- Is this the best way of performing these tasks? Waiting on data available via a EventHandler Event setting an AutoResetEvent?
- Do I need to explicitly add and remove the `EventHandler waitForEvent` to and from the `otherThread.DataChanged` handler? Or does the object, when deleted/cleanedup remove itself from the Event list?
- Are there library provided methods that do all of this for me? Or is there a more `C#` kind of way to do these things?

(note, my background is in Embedded C++ and know *some* C#) So forgive me if the C# looks kind of bad. Here to learn ;-)

Comment: why DataChanged doesn't send last value?

Comment: You can have a look at [task-base async pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) or use `IAsyncResult` / `AsyncWaitHandle` to return the data from thread, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/blocking-application-execution-using-an-asyncwaithandle) is an example

Comment: @Fildor am now, but that does not satisfy the requirement of "wait for new data, and then get the latest value"

Comment: @Selvin the data itself is more complex than an int and the `GetLastData()` method has the logic of handling that complexity.

Comment: `List` and other generic collections are not thread-safe and are not supposed to be used in multi-threaded context. You can use concurrent collections with `BlockingCollection` to achieve this.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev even with manual synchronization? (Locks/Mutexes?)

Comment: if you only ever want the **last** value - do you actually need the list at all? What happens if the producer out-paces the consumer? But other than that, this sound like a job for `Channel<T>` (see: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels) if you need multiple items, and maybe just a custom awaitable otherwise

Comment: The C# way unfortunately requires VS2019 and .NET core 3.0: https://www.infoq.com/articles/Async-Streams/ And IMO VS 2019 has way too many unfixed bugs to be usable.

Comment: @Soonts you don't need async streams to publish data asynchronously and async streams *can* be used in earlier C# versions *and* .NET Framework using the proper NuGet packages. As for VS 2019, I'm using it for quite some time and I wouldn't agree about the bugs

Comment: @MarcGravell I need all the data generated. Small context: it is a data acquisition of NiDaq's where the information of all the lines 'monitored' is stored in this list. Which can be printed in the case of a test failure so we have a trace of all signals. The current tests only require a 'latest value' and some require 'wait for new sample latest value'.

Answer (score 2):

Since (comments) you actually need all the data, not just the latest; this seems like a perfect fit for `Channel<T>`; `Channel<T>` is **explicitly designed** for fully asynchronous (`async`/`await`) producer/consumer scenarios, and has configuration options for bounded vs unbounded, threading models, multiple vs single producer/consumer, and what to do when a bounded channel is full (delay, drop old, drop new, etc).

So basically: consider using `Channel<T>`; it is available on nuget, including support down to netstandard1.3 and net46: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Channels/

A good usage overview is available here: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I would do something like this:

```
/// <summary>This class is thread safe, you can call methods from any thread.</summary>
class Measures
{
    readonly object syncRoot = new object();
    int? lastValue = null;
    readonly List<int> buffer = new List<int>();

    /// <summary>Provide a new value</summary>
    public void produce( int val )
    {
        lock( syncRoot )
        {
            lastValue = val;
            buffer.Add( val );
            Monitor.PulseAll( syncRoot );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Get a single last value, or null if there's none currently.</summary>
    public int? getLast()
    {
        lock( syncRoot )
            return lastValue;
    }

    /// <summary>Block the calling thread waiting for the next result.</summary>
    public int getNext()
    {
        lock( syncRoot )
        {
            Monitor.Wait( syncRoot );
            return lastValue.Value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Get all measures accumulated so far.</summary>
    public List<int> getAll()
    {
        lock( syncRoot )
        {
            List<int> result = new List<int>( buffer.Count );
            result.AddRange( buffer );
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The [Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor?view=netframework-4.8) class (it’s the same one `lock` statement compiles into) is implemented in .NET runtime, often faster than events.

---

If you have many consuming threads, more than CPU cores, you probably don’t want to block threads. Here's a non-blocking version:

```
/// <summary>This class is thread safe, you can call methods from any threads.</summary>
class Measures
{
    readonly object syncRoot = new object();
    int? lastValue = null;
    TaskCompletionSource<int> tcsConsumeNext = null;
    readonly List<int> buffer = new List<int>();

    /// <summary>Provide a new value</summary>
    public void produce( int val )
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs;
        lock( syncRoot )
        {
            lastValue = val;
            buffer.Add( val );
            tcs = tcsConsumeNext;
            tcsConsumeNext = null;
        }
        tcs?.TrySetResult( val );
    }

    /// <summary>Get a single last value, or null if there's none.</summary>
    public int? getLast()
    {
        lock( syncRoot )
            return lastValue;
    }

    /// <summary>Get a task which will complete with the next value.</summary>
    public Task<int> getNext()
    {
        lock( syncRoot )
        {
            if( null == tcsConsumeNext )
            {
                // Some setup is required to make sure the producing thread doesn't run the continuations.
                tcsConsumeNext = new TaskCompletionSource<int>( TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously );
            }
            return tcsConsumeNext.Task;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Get all measures accumulated so far.</summary>
    public List<int> getAll()
    {
        lock( syncRoot )
        {
            List<int> result = new List<int>( buffer.Count );
            result.AddRange( buffer );
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```